# How to set vcxproj platform toolset using VisualStudio AddIn

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, add-in

I have a very large VS2012 solution with more than two hundreds vcxprojs which have been just upgraded from VS2008. By default VS2012 set the PlatformToolset to v110 for the upgraded vcxprojs. However, I need it to be set to v110_xp instead and I am thinking to create a simple AddIn to do so. However, I couldn't find which object property should I set to change the PlatformToolset.

I know that I can achieve the same objective using some sort of externals scripts, but I have a set of similar AddIns as well and I prefer to manage Solution/Project related tools using AddIn.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My colleague found the following site which answers my question.

http://kobyk.wordpress.com/2011/11/26/modifying-a-visual-c-2010-projects-platform-toolset-programmatically-with-ivcrulepropertystorage/